# Dynamic property in CSS of Styled Component and ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, jsx, styled-components

I am trying to set dynamically and image like this:

```
const IntroVideoWrapper = styled.div`
  background-image: url("../images/${(props)=>props.image_prefix}_427.png"); 
`;
```

However, the image is not being displayed. when I look in the debugger tools, it is being parsed like:

```
background-image: url("../images/" + selfie + "_427.png" )
```

instead of:

```
background-image: url("../images/selfie_427.png" )
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function has to return the entire string like the following

```
background: ${props => `url('../images/${props.selfie}_427.png.jpg')`};
```

[Sandboxed](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-theme-provider-dbzfb)

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in using `` in first you tried.

```
background-image: url(${props => `../images/${props.image_prefix}_427.png`});
```

Comment: I am getting Unexpected token, expected ";" pointing at the "u" in "url"

Comment: didnt help I added the Styled Components div

Comment: background-image: url("../images/" + selfie + "_427.png" )

Comment: Did you add prop image_prefix like `<IntroVideoWrapper image_prefix="selfie" />` ?

Comment: What is the result of my answer in Chrome dev tools?